# jQuery, change class text of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My HTML is generated by the website and I can't change this:

```
<div>
    <span class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nr1" name="X"> 
        <label for="X">
            <span class="Y">
                <span class="title">Text nr 1</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to change the text in `<span class="title">` when `checkbox id=nr1` is checked. (I have many of these checkboxes with different IDs and different texts and I want to change the text always to the same outcome when the box is checked.

I have made this jQuery code:

```
$('#submit').on("click", function(){
   $("input:checkbox(:checked)").each(function() {
      $(this).find( $(".title").text("Checked"));
   });  
});
```

But it doesn't seem to select the correct object as I can't get the output back correctly. it seems to do "nothing" (I can't enable errors in the system I'm working on so I can't see why it would not work).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the `#submit` element? I feel like this is the root of the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to change the text as the user checks or unchecks the check boxes? Or do you really only want the text changed when clicking the submit button?

Comment: The text only needs to be changed on clicking the submit button. (It is passed to an email after submitting.)

Comment: The #submit is a span (can't change that either) but testing other functions with this same .on (click) works even if the #submit is a span so it's not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance I see two issues:

1. This doesn't make much sense as a *find* operation: `$(this).find( $(".title").text("Checked"));`
2. Even when corrected, you won't find `.title` *within* `input:checkbox(:checked)` because it's not a child of that element.

The first issue is just more familiarity with jQuery syntax and functions.  The second requires an understanding of DOM traversal.  Rather than looking *within* the checkbox element, traverse up to a common parent (e.g. `span.wrapper`) then then find the target within *that* element.

For example:

```js
$('#submit').on("click", function(){
   $("input:checkbox(:checked)").each(function() {
      $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.title').text('Checked');
   });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nr1" name="X"> 
        <label for="X">
            <span class="Y">
                <span class="title">Text nr 1</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works on the front end. But the form that I am submitting 
does not contain the changed text. Do you know how I can send this changed text to the submitted form as well? –

Comment: @J.K.: It's not clear what you mean.  There's no `<form>` in the code shown, and only one `<input>` which has no `value`.  Did you mean to add a `value` to your `<input>`?  Something else?  In any event, it sounds like whatever you're describing is unrelated to the question asked above.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought this question was the problem but it turns out I had a different problem (which is not covered by my original question). I will work with this now to see if I can figure out the rest. Either way this answer has brought me one step closer to solving my ultimate problem. So I'm going to mark your answer as the solution to end the cycle on this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), as [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches descendants, and the span isn't a descendant of the checkbox, but it is a descendant of the next element in the DOM.

Also, the proper selector syntax for your example is `$("input:checkbox:checked")`, not `$("input:checkbox(:checked)")`

```js
$('#submit').on("click", function() {
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).next().find($("span.title")).text("Checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nr1" name="X"> 
        <label for="nr1">
            <span class="Y">
                <span class="title">Text nr 1</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div><div>
    <span class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nr2" name="X"> 
        <label for="nr2">
            <span class="Y">
                <span class="title">Text nr 1</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div><div>
    <span class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="nr3" name="X"> 
        <label for="nr3">
            <span class="Y">
                <span class="title">Text nr 1</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </span>
</div>

<button id="submit">
submit
</button>
```

Note that the label's `for` attribute should match the `ID` of another element, not the `name`.

> The value of the for attribute must be a single id for a labelable
> form-related element in the same document as the  element

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense and it works on the front end. But the form that gets submitted does not contain the changed text. Do you know how I can send this changed text to the submitted form as well?

Comment: Eventually I figured my problem is not solved by the question I asked. Your answer is working fine. Thanks for your help.